# VBA: Calling one sub repeatedly and scope of variables

Tags: vba

My code as a whole works for me without issues, but what I want to improve is a small part right out of the middle of it. I hope it's ok to post a simplified snippet here that just shows the structure (it's not something you can copy paste and it works), but I'll try to explain what it is about. If this is against the rules, let me know.

---

I have a workbook that functions as a database (`wbDB`). I look for the number of an object (`objectNumber`) and, if found, add it to a sheet (`wsTest`) in another workbook via `Sub AddObject`.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const fRowType As Long = 4
Public Const fRowClosing As Long = fRowType + 1
Public Const fRowLoan As Long = fRowType + 4
'[there are about 30 of those fRow variables; they are needed in another _
 module, that's why they are public]

Dim wbDB As Workbook
Dim wsDB As Worksheet, wsTest As Worksheet

Dim lColTest As Long

Sub AddObject(ByVal objectNumber As String, ByVal rngObjects As Range)
    Const colType As String = "A"
    Const colClosing As String = "BN"
    Const colLoan As String = "CD"
    '[same as fRows, I have over 30 of these "col"-variables]

    Dim rowObject As Long
    Dim foundCell As Range

    Set wbDB = Application.Workbooks("Database.xlsx")
    Set wsDB = wbDB.Sheets(2)
    Set wsTest = ActiveSheet

    '---Find object in rngObjects and set rowObject to respective row
    Set foundCell = rngObjects.Find(What:=objectNumber, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If foundCell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Object " & objectNumber & "wasn't found and will be skipped."
        Exit Sub
    Else
        rowObject = foundCell.Row
    End If

    lColTest = wsTest.Cells(12, wsTest.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
'Type
    Call ImportData(rowObject, colType, fRowType)
'Closing
    Call ImportData(rowObject, colClosing, fRowClosing)
'Loan
    Call ImportData(rowObject, colLoan, fRowLoan)
'[again, there are 30+ of these calls]

End Sub


Sub ImportData(ByVal rowDB As Long, ByVal colDB As String, ByVal fRowSection As Long)
    wsTest.Cells(fRowSection, lColTest + 1).Value = wsDB.Cells(rowDB, colDB).Value
End Sub
```

If you look at `Sub ImportData`: It requires `lColTest`, a module-wide variable, which I initialize in `Sub AddObject`. On the other hand, `rowObject` is needed just as often, but I put it as one of the parameters of `ImportData`. What is better practice? From what I've read is that the wider the scope of a variable, the less desirable it is. However, if it is one of the parameters, I currently copy paste it about 30 times with every `Call` and every additional parameter makes it a little less readable too.

My idea as the "cleanest" solution would be: put it in as parameter and instead of typing out every `Call`, I loop through it. Would you agree with that? If the answer is yes, I'd need an array or something similar.

1. What's the best option here since I need always need a pair of values (column and first row)?
2. Is there an efficient or readable way to fill the array with all these variables?

Comment: Please see [_What to do when someone answers_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). I have rolled back Rev 2 → 1

Comment: FWIW a simplified snippet isn't against the rules per se, but makes you needlessly walk a thin blurry line between actual code and pseudocode, the latter being off-topic. Best include the 30+ constants instead of just saying "there are 30 more like this" - code that's not in the post isn't reviewable, and you generally get better feedback when you simply include your code exactly as you have it. Don't worry about making a long post, we're used to that on this site (and the post length limit is *twice* that of [so] for a reason!).

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Thank you, I'll keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Thank you for the tips. In this case, if I were to include everything and not at least simplify it, the code would be fairly long and, more importantly, without both the workbooks/data structure you can't get it to run. So what is the best thing to do in this case? Upload the file somewhere? Because that was my issue - I thought if you can't run it anyway, removing the clutter might make it more understandable.

Answer (score 2):

```
Public Const fRowType As Long = 4
Public Const fRowClosing As Long = fRowType + 1
Public Const fRowLoan As Long = fRowType + 4
'[there are about 30 of those fRow variables; they are needed in another _
 module, that's why they are public]
```

First of all, they're not "variables" they're "constants".

Second, that's screaming for an array or `scripting.dictionary` to hold them instead of a hoard of `Const`. They could even be pulled into a class that can easily be initialized provided with `Get`ter properties (if the values are as fixed as `Const` would indicate) then the class can be passed around wherever it's needed.

Comment: Fixed the constant/variable mix up. I have to look into classes, I don't have experience with them. As for an array: I get that it makes sense to store them in there, but to make sure I'm not missing something very basic: It wouldn't save lines of code, I'd still have to initiliaze them the same way?

Comment: @Alex "Saving lines of code" is a pointless exercise, though, actually it will. You'll have one `Dim rowClosing(30) as Long` statement, _et voila_ 30 variables declared. Yes, you'll have to populate them, but that can now be done in a loop instead of 1 by 1.

Comment: [here](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2020/02/27/vba-classes-gateway-to-solid/) is a great, basic intro to classes and OOP in VBA.

Comment: I'm gonna read up on that, I have come in touch with OOP a few times, but always kind of shied away from it. To make sure I get what you mean by "you'll have to populate them, but that can now be done in a loop ":  obviously an array will allow me to do the `Call ImportData` in one loop, but initializing the variables would still need to be one by one (`Public Const fRowType As Long = 4` etc and populalting the array would then be `arrayRows = (fRowType, fRowClosing...)`. I still see the advantage, but I wanna make sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: @Alex perhaps if you provide more of your code (in particular the initialization code) I could rewrite it into a loop for you. At this point, all I know is one fixed value and a couple of minor variations on it. I'd need to see how the different values vary in order to know how to build the loop.